# Json.net how to use jsonpath with "$."

Tags: c#, json.net, jsonpath

I'm trying to use json.net from json as follows:

```
String JSONString =
@"[
    {
      ""category"": ""reference"",
      ""author"": ""Nigel Rees"",
      ""title"": ""Sayings of the Century"",
      ""price"": 8.95
    },
    {
      ""category"": ""fiction"",
      ""author"": ""Still Here"",
      ""title"": ""Test remove title"",
      ""price"": 12.99,
      ""isbn"": ""0-553-21311-3""
    }
  ]";

JObject JSONObject;
JSONObject = JObject.Parse(JSONString);

String JSONPath = @"$[0].title";
JSONObject.SelectToken(JSONPath);
```

Getting Exception:

```
ST.Acxiom.Test.DataJSONTest.DataJSONClass.GetToken: Newtonsoft.Json.JsonException :   Property '$' does not exist on JObject.
```

- What I'm doing wrong, even though I'm using valid jsonpath but still
  getting error.
- Is "$." not supported?
- How to access Array item in
  json in above example?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

1. Using `JObject.Parse` from your example throws `JsonReaderException` with the latest Json.net version. You have to use either `JToken.Parse` or `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject`.
2. [SelectToken](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/html/SelectToken.htm) is intended to select child nodes so `$` is not supported. You can access array item like this:

```c#
var jArray = JToken.Parse(JSONString); //It's actually a JArray, not a JObject
var jTitle = jArray.SelectToken("[0].title");
var title = (string)jTitle;
```