# Recursively entering Json object based on string

Tags: c++, json, esp8266

I've got the following json object:

```
{
    "ESP_IN_PC_OUT":{
        "track":{
            "1":{
                "mute":{
                    "type":"LED",
                    "pins":[4]
                }
            },
            "2":{
                "mute":{
                    "type":"LED",
                    "pins":[5]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I want to enter the object, depending on a string of the format "/index1/index2/index3 ..." (The string is the address of an OSC message). For example, "/track/2/mute" should return a Json object like this:

```
{
    "type":"LED",
    "pins":[5]
}
```

So that I can access the type, the pins array, and some other values that will be implemented later.

I'm using the [Arduino JSON library](https://github.com/bblanchon/ArduinoJson) on an ESP8266. This is the code I've tried:

```
#include <ArduinoJson.h>

char *jsonstr = "{\n    \"ESP_IN_PC_OUT\":{\n        \"track\":{\n            \"1\":{\n                \"mute\":{\n                    \"type\":\"LED\",\n                    \"pins\":[4]\n                }\n            },\n            \"2\":{\n                \"mute\":{\n                    \"type\":\"LED\",\n                    \"pins\":[5]\n                }\n            }\n        }\n    },\n\n\n    \"ESP_OUT_PC_IN\":{\n        \"analog\":{\n        },\n        \"digital\":{\n            \"16\":\"/track/1/mute\"\n        }\n    }\n}"; 

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);

  DynamicJsonBuffer jsonBuffer;

  JsonObject& root = jsonBuffer.parseObject(jsonstr);
  if (!root.success()) {
    Serial.println("parseObject() failed");
    return;
  }

  Serial.println((const char*) root["ESP_IN_PC_OUT"]["track"]["2"]["mute"]["type"]); // prints "LED"
  Serial.println();

  char *address = "/track/2/mute";     // _____Interesting part_____
  char *tmp = strtok(address,"/");
  JsonObject& tmpJson = root["ESP_IN_PC_OUT"];
  bool success = true;
  while(tmp != NULL && success == true){
    Serial.println(tmp);
    if(tmpJson.containsKey(tmp)){
      tmpJson = tmpJson[tmp];        // Error: use of deleted function 'ArduinoJson::JsonObject& ArduinoJson::JsonObject::operator=(const ArduinoJson::JsonObject&)'
      tmp = strtok(NULL,"/");
    } else {
      success = false;
    }
  }
  if(success == true){
    Serial.println((const char*)tmpJson["type"]);
  } else {
    Serial.println("Address not found");
  }
}

void loop() {
}
```

However, this gives me the following error message:

```
JSON_OSC_settings2:26: error: use of deleted function 'ArduinoJson::JsonObject& ArduinoJson::JsonObject::operator=(const ArduinoJson::JsonObject&)'

       tmpJson = tmpJson[tmp];

               ^

In file included from C:\Users\Pieter\Documents\Arduino\libraries\ArduinoJson-master/include/ArduinoJson.hpp:12:0,

                 from C:\Users\Pieter\Documents\Arduino\libraries\ArduinoJson-master/include/ArduinoJson.h:8,

                 from C:\Users\Pieter\Documents\Arduino\libraries\ArduinoJson-master/ArduinoJson.h:8,

                 from C:\Users\Pieter\Documents\Arduino\JSON_OSC_settings2\JSON_OSC_settings2.ino:1:

C:\Users\Pieter\Documents\Arduino\libraries\ArduinoJson-master/include/ArduinoJson/JsonObject.hpp:38:7: note: 'ArduinoJson::JsonObject& ArduinoJson::JsonObject::operator=(const ArduinoJson::JsonObject&)' is implicitly deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed:

 class JsonObject : public Internals::JsonPrintable<JsonObject>,

       ^

In file included from C:\Users\Pieter\Documents\Arduino\libraries\ArduinoJson-master/include/ArduinoJson/JsonArray.hpp:13:0,

                 from C:\Users\Pieter\Documents\Arduino\libraries\ArduinoJson-master/include/ArduinoJson.hpp:11,

                 from C:\Users\Pieter\Documents\Arduino\libraries\ArduinoJson-master/include/ArduinoJson.h:8,

                 from C:\Users\Pieter\Documents\Arduino\libraries\ArduinoJson-master/ArduinoJson.h:8,

                 from C:\Users\Pieter\Documents\Arduino\JSON_OSC_settings2\JSON_OSC_settings2.ino:1:

C:\Users\Pieter\Documents\Arduino\libraries\ArduinoJson-master/include/ArduinoJson/Internals/ReferenceType.hpp:32:18: error: 'ArduinoJson::Internals::ReferenceType& ArduinoJson::Internals::ReferenceType::operator=(const ArduinoJson::Internals::ReferenceType&)' is private

   ReferenceType& operator=(const ReferenceType&);

                  ^

In file included from C:\Users\Pieter\Documents\Arduino\libraries\ArduinoJson-master/include/ArduinoJson.hpp:12:0,

                 from C:\Users\Pieter\Documents\Arduino\libraries\ArduinoJson-master/include/ArduinoJson.h:8,

                 from C:\Users\Pieter\Documents\Arduino\libraries\ArduinoJson-master/ArduinoJson.h:8,

                 from C:\Users\Pieter\Documents\Arduino\JSON_OSC_settings2\JSON_OSC_settings2.ino:1:

C:\Users\Pieter\Documents\Arduino\libraries\ArduinoJson-master/include/ArduinoJson/JsonObject.hpp:38:7: error: within this context

 class JsonObject : public Internals::JsonPrintable<JsonObject>,

       ^

exit status 1
use of deleted function 'ArduinoJson::JsonObject& ArduinoJson::JsonObject::operator=(const ArduinoJson::JsonObject&)'
```

How can I solve this? What different approach could I take?

Comment: why are you trying to redefine reference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not a C developer but what could help you is called »JSONPath«, which is meant to be the counterpart of xPath for JSON. Probably you can find a library which can do that.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14348567/json-net-how-to-use-jsonpath-with) seems to be a similar thing.

Comment: This seems to be the right solution indeed, thanks! The maker of the library also answered my question [on GitHub](https://github.com/bblanchon/ArduinoJson/issues/343), pointers seem the way to go.

Comment: If it solves your problem you may feel free to accept the answer. This would be my first answer to c++ question and if accepted, some kind of real lucky shot :)

Comment: @tttapa: if it solve your problem, it could be nice to share the answer from github here.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a function to parse simple json path string and extract a value from a json string. See https://github.com/bblanchon/ArduinoJson/issues/821 for details.

I recently adapted it to ArduinoJson6 - I have to admit I am not a c++ guy, so have mercy with my code:

```
// parse jsonPaths like $.foo[1].bar.baz[2][3].value equals to foo[1].bar.baz[2][3].value
String parseJson(char* jsonString, char *jsonPath) {

    Serial.printf("parsing String '%s'\n", jsonString);

    String jsonValue;
    DynamicJsonDocument jsonBuffer(64000); // fixme!!!!

    DeserializationError err = deserializeJson(jsonBuffer, jsonString);
    JsonVariant root = jsonBuffer.as<JsonVariant>();
    JsonVariant element = root;

    if (!err) {
        // parse jsonPath and navigate through json object:
        char pathElement[40];
        int pathIndex = 0;

        Serial.printf("parsing Path '%s'\n", jsonPath);
        for (int i = 0; jsonPath[i] != '\0'; i++){
            if (jsonPath[i] == '$') {
                element = root;
            } else if (jsonPath[i] == '.') {
                if (pathIndex > 0) {
                    pathElement[pathIndex++] = '\0';
                    //printf("pathElement '%s'\n", pathElement);
                    pathIndex = 0;
                    element = element[pathElement];
                    if (element == nullptr) {
                        Serial.printf("failed to parse key %s\n", pathElement);
                        return nullptr;
                    }
                }
            } else if ((jsonPath[i] >= 'a' && jsonPath[i] <= 'z') 
                    || (jsonPath[i] >= 'A' && jsonPath[i] <= 'Z') 
                    || (jsonPath[i] >= '0' && jsonPath[i] <= '9')
                    || jsonPath[i] == '-' || jsonPath[i] == '_'
                    ) {
                pathElement[pathIndex++] = jsonPath[i];
            } else if (jsonPath[i] == '[') {
                if (pathIndex > 0) {
                    pathElement[pathIndex++] = '\0';
                    // printf("pathElement '%s'\n", pathElement);
                    pathIndex = 0;
                    element = element[pathElement];
                    if (element == nullptr) {
                        Serial.printf("failed in parsing key %s\n", pathElement);
                        return nullptr;
                    }
                }
            } else if (jsonPath[i] == ']') {
                pathElement[pathIndex++] = '\0';
                int arrayIndex = strtod(pathElement, NULL);
                // printf("index '%s' = %d\n", pathElement, arrayIndex);
                pathIndex = 0;
                element = element[arrayIndex];
                if (element == nullptr) {
                    Serial.printf("failed in parsing index %d\n", arrayIndex);
                    return nullptr;
                }
            }
        }  
        // final token if any:
        if (pathIndex > 0) {
            pathElement[pathIndex++] = '\0';
            // printf("pathElement '%s'\n", pathElement);
            pathIndex = 0;
            element = element[pathElement];
            if (element == nullptr) {
                Serial.printf("failed in parsing key %s\n", pathElement);
                return nullptr;
            }
        }

        jsonValue = element.as<String>();
    } else {
        jsonValue = nullptr;
    }
    return jsonValue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to point to the sub-object, you can simply use :

```
JsonObject& tmpJson = root["ESP_IN_PC_OUT"]["track"]["2"]["mute"];
```

Next you can check if this sub-object exists comparing it to `JsonObject::invalid` like this :

```
bool success = (tmpJson != JsonObject::invalid());

if(success == true){
    Serial.println((const char*)tmpJson["type"]);
} else {
    Serial.println("Address not found");
}
```

If a part of the path doesnot exists, `operator[]` will return a reference to `JsonObject::invalid` then accessing to its child will also return a reference to `JsonObject::invalid`, then it is safe to iterate to unexisting child.